# AccessKey Property not worked in Mozila firefox

Tags: asp.net, mozilla, access-keys

I tried by using Alt+E in Mozilla Firefox.

```
First Name<asp:TextBox AccessKey="A" ID ="fstName" runat ="server" /><br />
```

What's Wrong With My Code?

Comment: It worked in a Chrome & IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>  for AccessKey